# How to Generate Visual Studio Project Files from Unreal Engine .uproject file with a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit

I have a batch file as follows to clean my UE project.

```
del *.sln
rmdir /s /q .vs
rmdir /s /q Binaries
rmdir /s /q Intermediate
rmdir /s /q Saved
rmdir /s /q DerivedDataCache
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Epic Games\Launcher\Engine\Binaries\Win64\UnrealVersionSelector.exe" /projectfiles Attaching.uproject
```

Unfortunately, when I run the batch, I get an error as follows:

[image]

I found the last command in the batch by reverse-engineering as shown below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

## Question

What is the correct way to generate Visual Studio project files from a batch file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After wasting a lot of time, I found the solution. We have to fully qualify the project path.

```
echo off

del *.sln
rmdir /s /q .vs
rmdir /s /q Binaries
rmdir /s /q Intermediate
rem rmdir /s /q Saved
rmdir /s /q DerivedDataCache


set MyUVS="C:\Program Files (x86)\Epic Games\Launcher\Engine\Binaries\Win64\UnrealVersionSelector.exe"
set MyUBT="f:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.26\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool.exe"

rem change Transformation to your own project name
set MyFullPath="%cd%\Transformation"


%MyUVS% /projectfiles %MyFullPath%.uproject

%MyUBT% Development Win64 -Project=%MyFullPath%.uproject -TargetType=Editor -Progress -NoEngineChanges -NoHotReloadFromIDE

%MyFullPath%.uproject

%MyFullPath%.sln
```

I hope this answer is also useful for others in the future!

Comment: What should I call this file? Where should I save it? How can I use it?

Comment: This is a windows batch file. They're saved with the .bat extension and executed with the command line (cmd.exe).

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Change this to the path to your Unreal Engine's "UnrealVersionSelector.exe"
set "UEVersionSelector=C:\Program Files (x86)\Epic Games\Launcher\Engine\Binaries\Win64\UnrealVersionSelector.exe"

rem Change this to the path to your UnrealBuildTool
set "UnrealBuildTool=C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.3\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.exe"

rem Get the directory of the batch file
set "BatchFileDir=%~dp0"

rem Find the .uproject file in the batch file directory
for %%i in ("%BatchFileDir%*.uproject") do set "UProjectFile=%%i"

if not defined UProjectFile (
    echo .uproject file not found in the batch file directory.
    pause
    exit /b
)

rem Extract the project name from the .uproject file
for /f "usebackq tokens=2,* delims=:" %%a in ("!UProjectFile!") do (
    set "ProjectName=%%~b"
    set "ProjectName=!ProjectName:^"=!"
    set "ProjectName=!ProjectName: =!"
)

echo Cleaning project files...

rem Remove the Visual Studio solution file if it exists
set "SolutionFile=%BatchFileDir%!ProjectName!.sln"
if exist "!SolutionFile!" (
    del "!SolutionFile!"
    echo Deleted "!SolutionFile!"
) else (
    echo "!SolutionFile!" not found. Skipping deletion.
)

rem Remove Intermediate and Saved folders if they exist without confirmation prompt
rmdir /s /q "!BatchFileDir!Intermediate" 2>nul
rmdir /s /q "!BatchFileDir!Saved" 2>nul

rem Remove the additional files and folders
rmdir /s /q "!BatchFileDir!.vs" 2>nul
del /q "!BatchFileDir!.vsconfig" 2>nul
rmdir /s /q "!BatchFileDir!Binaries" 2>nul
rmdir /s /q "!BatchFileDir!Build" 2>nul
rmdir /s /q "!BatchFileDir!DerivedDataCache" 2>nul

echo Cleaning completed.

echo Generating project files...

rem Generate project files using UnrealVersionSelector
"%UEVersionSelector%" -projectfiles "!UProjectFile!"

echo Generating Visual Studio project files...

rem Generate Visual Studio project files using UnrealBuildTool
"%UnrealBuildTool%" Development Win64 -Project="!UProjectFile!" -TargetType=Editor

echo Generation completed.

rem Pause the script so you can see the output before it closes
pause
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).